How to separate a string and convert it to date in Google Big Query
I have a column full of timestamps titled "DateTime" that are actually a string data type. While most of the entries are in this first format: 01012023050000AM (meaning January 1st 2023 at 5 AM EST), some of the entries are in this second format: 2023-01-01 05:00:00+00 (also January 1st 2023 at 5 AM EST).
I am trying to convert this string data into date data so that I can find the difference in values from another column between the first and last day of each month throughout 2023. I tried using PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%c", DateTime) but got an error for some of the dates such as Failed to parse input string "09042023050000AM
The timestamp is taken at 5 AM each day so the hours-minutes-second portion is not needed, and most of the timestamps under the second format date further back then needed. I am wondering how do I get rid of the "050000AM" and how do I exclude any dates of the second format "2023-01-01 05:00:00+00" before converting to a date?
I apologize I am brand new to SQL and Google Big Query so any help is appreciated!

I would start by using SAFE.PARSE_TIMESTAMP() feature which will output NULL instead of an error when it encounters a string timestamp that it can't parse successfully. Then it's just a matter of working through your edge cases to convert them through string manipulation or regex or whatever else you can throw at it to turn it into a parseable timestamp.

in a case expression, use INSTR() to detect if "-" exists in the string, if no then use the 8 LEFT() characters of string as ddmmyyyy mask for conversion, if yes (to "-")  then use LEFT() 10 chars for conversion as yyyy-mm-dd mask for conversion (and use the safe approach for each conversion) - also - if you only want date then perhaps use parse_date()

If there's only two formats, you could use coalesce() + safe.parse_timestamp(), as in the example below:
select
  DateTime,
  coalesce(
    safe.parse_timestamp('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z', DateTime),
    safe.parse_timestamp('%m%d%Y%H%M%S%p', DateTime)
  ) as my_new_datetime

which will return:
| DateTime               | my_new_datetime         |
|------------------------|-------------------------|
| 01012023050000AM       | 2023-01-01 05:00:00 UTC |
| 2023-01-01 05:00:00+00 | 2023-01-01 05:00:00 UTC |

Using this combination, you will make sure that:

if a new format is added, it will return null instead of an error
when a new format is added, if at all, you will just need to add a new line in the coalesce()

